# Как создать тему opencart?

Tags: opencart

Я скопировал тему default, переименовал в шапке, поменял ссылки. В админке, в поле шаблон, ничего не поменялось.

Что еще нужно отредактировать, что бы появилась тема?

Comment: в админке выбери новую тему)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCart 3 (дублирование темы default):

Создаём дубликат стандартной темы

`<install_dir>/catalog/view/theme/MyTheme`

Редактируем стили в twig  `<install_dir>/catalog/view/theme/MyTheme/template/common/header.twig`

Было:

```
<link href="catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Стало:

```
<install_dir>/catalog/view/theme/MyTheme/template/common/header.twig
```

Дублируем 3 файла extensions:

```
<install_dir>/admin/language/en-gb/extension/theme/default.php
<install_dir>/admin/view/template/extension/theme/default.twig
<install_dir>/admin/controller/extension/theme/default.php
```

И даём им название MyTheme вместо default.
Далее редактируем MyTheme.php `<install_dir>/admin/language/en-gb/extension/theme/MyTheme.php`

Так же default меняем на MyTheme

В файле MyTheme.twig

`<install_dir>/admin/view/template/extension/theme/MyTheme.twig`

Находим `theme/default` и меняем на `theme/MyTheme`

После этого тема должна появиться в админке.

Не так давно сам искал и нашел [данный материал](https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=187122#p690819), по нему все получилось